# “apt-get: command not found” issue on raspberry pi os built using Buildroot

Tags: apt, cross-compilation, buildroot

I have built a sdcard.img for raspberry pi using Buildroot. When I run apt-get command it throws error "apt-get: command not found". I did not find apt-get/dpkg package to enable in 'make menuconfig' options. Now I'm trying to run cross-compiled opencv program on my Rpi but some shared libraries are missing and I want to install these libraries using apt repository (as I already did it on standard Raspbian Stretch os & program run successfully).

I googled it, there's no solution for Buildroot rasbpbian os. Also I tried downloading and installing .deb packages for apt/apt-get/dpkg, didn't work.

apt-get: command not found

I want to cross-compile a kernel which will have all the necessary packages such as apt/dpkg, bin and lib files. Or for the time being to get the work done need guidance to install apt/dpkg packages on Rpi buildroot os.

Answer (score 3):

The `apt` command is the Debian solution to download packages from a repository, including their dependencies. If you want to use `apt`, you have to create a system that is based on these packages.

If you create a system with Buildroot, you can't use `apt`, even if you compile an `apt` program for that system. Whatever you want to install later with `apt` would most likely at least need the standard C library. Your system obviously already has a C library, because it wouldn't work without. But that library is not known to `apt`, so it would try to download and install the C library, overwriting the already present library. As it doesn't make sense to use `apt` on a Buildroot system, the Buildroot menu doesn't offer that.

In short, if you start with a package system (`apt`, `yum`, `zypper` or whatever), then stay with that system.

Is there a reason why you use Buildroot instead of Raspian?

> I want to cross-compile a kernel which will have all the necessary packages such as apt/dpkg, bin and lib files.

There seems to be a misunderstanding what kernel means. A kernel is just a kernel and doesn't contain packages, binaries or libraries.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new in the field of embedded-linux development. I understood that I can't use apt in Buildroot system. The reason why I chose Buildroot instead of Raspbian is that I want to cross-compile my entire opencv project in single 'make' and run it when board boots up.

Answer (score 1):

Debian (and Raspbian) have a very minimalistic installation package called **debootstrap**. It contains everything to run a very small Debian/Raspbian system only with essential needed programs. Every Debian installer starts with it. It contains also **apt-get** so you can build your Debian system from scratch step by step. *debootstrap* only needs a running linux system and **wget** and nothing else to get installed. With the Buildroot rasbpbian operating system you have a running system and it should not be a big problem to get *wget* installed from a package.

I don't know if *debootstrap* is usable for your setup but you may have a look at it at [install Debian with debootstrap](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en). I have made an installation using a Linux operating system on a laptop with intel cpu: [Howto install RPi with debootstrap](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/78232/79866).