# Change to Testing Suite

Tags: apt, source.list

I want to run raspbian testing (bullseye). By default the following repos were enabled

```
http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
```

The 2nd one doesnt offer the bullseye suite. Is it actually needed at all?

Comment: I think you're about 18 months too early. Buster has only been supported since June 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you have an image of the Raspbian version that you can download from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ or from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/. But as far as I know there is no image available for the testing version **Raspbian Bullseye** so you have to install it from the repository.

There are two ways to install **Bullseye** from the repository:
full upgrade from **Buster**
bootstrapped from the repository

I prefer to use bootstrap because then you have a clean configuration and not modified old (from Buster) configuration files. How to do it you can refer to [Install base Raspbian from repository, not using an image](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/78232/79866) but I haven't tested it for this answer. So I will look only at the full upgrade.

There may be an additional problem with the firmware. I also haven't found specific one for **Bullseye** at http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/ but that is needed of course. So I try to use that for **Buster**.

Upgrading from **Buster** is very easy. Just flash a fresh Buster image, boot it in your RasPi and update it:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

Then just modify the first line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# from
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
# to
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi
```

Don't touch `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` so you will use the same kernel and firmware compiled for Buster.

Then execute again:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

Login and check:

```
rpi ~$  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
Release:        testing
Codename:       bullseye
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Rpi4B buster 2019jul10 Desktop software install search "bullseye" results one and only one package:

> Tools to manage Xen virtual servers xen-tools-4-8-1

So I will just install the whole lot.

Comment: OP is referring to Debian 11, code-named Bullseye, not any package.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi, Many thanks for pointing out my careless mistake. I did not realize that the OP was trying to install an OS, the Debian 11 Bullseye, not any package. My apologies for misleading everybody. Cheers.